# s_strip(s, del) function in C, is there any more optimized version than this one?

Tags: c, optimization

my first post here (it's a real pity I hadn't discovered this great community earlier).

Anyway, I've coded a C function that removes from string *s* any character contained in string *del*. I was wondering if there's room for improvement, speed-wise, especially for the part that looks for chars contained in *del*, inside the for-loop (I was using strpbrk(), but pmg wisely suggested strchr() ).

Bug-hunters are most welcome too! I think it's robust, but you never know.

Here's the code (thanks in advance for any answers)...

#### Current version

```
// remove from string s any char contained in string del (return modified s)
// alg:
// parse s via cp1, keep desired *cp1's by copying them via cp2 to the start of s
// null terminate & return the trimmed s

char *s_strip(char *s, const char *del)
{
    char *cp1;                      // for parsing the whole s
    char *cp2;                      // for keeping desired *cp1's

    for (cp1=s, cp2=s; *cp1; cp1++ )
        if ( !strchr(del, *cp1) )   // *cp1 is NOT contained in del (thanks pmg!)
            *cp2++ = *cp1;          // copy it via cp2

    *cp2 = 0;                       // null terminate the trimmed s
    return s;
}
```

---

#### Original version

```
char *s_strip(char *s, const char *del)
{
    char *cp1;                              // for parsing the whole s
    char *cp2;                              // for keeping desired *cp1's

    for (cp1=s, cp2=s; *cp1; cp1++ )
        if ( cp1 != strpbrk(cp1, del) ) {   // *cp1 is NOT contained in del
            *cp2 = *cp1;                    // copy it via cp2
            cp2++;
        }

    *cp2 = 0;                               // null terminate the trimmed s
    return s;
}
```

Comment: fyi, your code is vulnerable to overflow attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but what do you mean? What part is vulnerable?

Comment: @Daniel: It is hard to suffer overflows when you are only reducing (never increasing) the length of the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long are the input strings going to be, and how many characters are you going to be deleting, on average.  If you work with 8-bit code sets and longer source strings, think about:

```
char *s_strip(char *s, const char *del)
{
    char map[256] = { 0 };
    const unsigned char *up1 = (const unsigned char *)del;
    unsigned char *up2 = (unsigned char *)s;
    unsigned char *up3 = (unsigned char *)s;

    while (*up1 != '\0')
        map[*up1++] = 1;

    for ( ; *up2 != '\0'; up2++)
    {
        if (map[*up2] == 0)
            *up3++ = *up2;
    }
    *up3 = '\0';

    return (char *)up3;
}
```

This replaces the function call (`strpbrk()` or `strchr()`) with a simple array lookup at the cost of initializing the array on entry to the function.  If the processed strings are fairly long, this could easily pay itself back in the vastly reduced search time.

This version of the code returns a pointer to the null at the end of the string - which allows you to compute the length of the compressed string on return without calling `strlen()`.  I find this a more useful design than returning the pointer to the start of the string - I already knew where the string started, but I no longer know where it ends, yet the function `s_strip()` does know that.  (If we were able to start over, I'd lobby for the same design for `strcpy()` and `strcat()` too.)

The coercions to 'unsigned char' ensure that it works properly on machines with signed and unsigned characters.  I'm not really happy with the slathering of casts, but it is hard to avoid them (well, the cast assigning `s` to `up3` could be avoided by copying `up2 instead).

You probably could come up with a design that handles signed characters too, along the lines of:

```
char realmap[256] = { 0 };
char *map = &realmap[128];
```

You can then rely on the signed characters being in a range such that `map[-128]` .. `map[+127]` still lands within the `realmap` array.

---

The function above has been corrected a couple of times since it was first posted - it now seems to work consistently with the two solutions suggested in the question.  I put the three solutions into a test harness to time them, mainly because I was curious about how the map code would perform, having lost out to assembler code inline functions in the past.  The mapping solution very quickly shows itself to be fastest on my test system (Mac Mini 2 GHZ Intel Core 2 Duo, MacOS X 10.6.7, GCC 4.1.2).

The times are average times in seconds.  Each algorithm was given 10 runs.
The size is the size of the source string; the delete string was 22 characters (6 each of lower-case letters, upper-case letters and digits, plus 4 punctuation).  The data was a fixed string built from the letters, digits and punctuation in ASCII, repeated as often as necessary to reach the stated size, which excludes the terminating null.  Note that the timing includes copying the source string each time - the 'null' column indicates the time spent on the copying.

```
size     map        strchr     strpbrk    null       micro1     micro2
   2     0.000542   0.002292   0.001009   0.000106   0.000639   0.000707
   8     0.000654   0.004125   0.017524   0.000106   0.001012   0.000966
  32     0.001667   0.015815   0.063314   0.000196   0.002549   0.002247
 128     0.006385   0.064513   0.313749   0.000171   0.008455   0.007188
 512     0.022231   0.257910   1.293040   0.000282   0.013284   0.011829
2048     0.089066   1.035052   5.297966   0.000819   0.043391   0.037597
```

Even with very short source strings, the map algorithm is much faster than either the `strchr()` or `strpbrk()` algorithms (5-10 times as fast as the `strchr()` algorithm, and 5-50 times as fast as the `strpbrk()` algorithm), with the disparity growing with search string size.  (I did not expect this result - because there is setup overhead in the map code.)

The 'micro1' and 'micro2' algorithms correspond to the modifications suggested by [AShelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10396/ashelly).  When the strings are long enough (somewhere between 128 and 512 bytes is the switch-over), then the micro-optimized versions are quicker than the simple map.

---

#### Test Code

Contact me (see my profile) if you want the source for `timer.c`, `timer.h`.  I'd normally build them into a library and link with the library, but it was simpler to include the files in the program this time.

```
#include <string.h>

extern char *s_strip1(char *s, const char *del);
extern char *s_strip2(char *s, const char *del);
extern char *s_strip3(char *s, const char *del);

char *s_strip3(char *s, const char *del)
{
    char map[256] = { 0 };
    const unsigned char *up1 = (const unsigned char *)del;
    unsigned char *up2 = (unsigned char *)s;
    unsigned char *up3 = (unsigned char *)s;

    while (*up1 != '\0')
        map[*up1++] = 1;

    for ( ; *up2 != '\0'; up2++)
    {
        if (map[*up2] == 0)
            *up3++ = *up2;
    }
    *up3 = '\0';

    return (char *)up3;
}

char *s_strip2(char *s, const char *del)
{
    char *cp1;
    char *cp2;

    for (cp1=s, cp2=s; *cp1; cp1++ )
        if ( !strchr(del, *cp1) )
            *cp2++ = *cp1;

    *cp2 = 0;
    return s;
}

char *s_strip1(char *s, const char *del)
{
    char *cp1;
    char *cp2;

    for (cp1=s, cp2=s; *cp1; cp1++ )
        if ( cp1 != strpbrk(cp1, del) ) {
            *cp2 = *cp1;
            cp2++;
        }

    *cp2 = 0;
    return s;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include "timer.h"
#include "timer.c"

enum { NUM_REPEATS = 10000 };
typedef char *(*Function)(char *str, const char *del);

static void fill_bytes(char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    static const char source[] =
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "0123456789[]{}\\|,./?><;:'\"=+-_)(*&^%$#@!";
    char *end = buffer + buflen;

    while (buffer < end)
    {
        size_t numbytes = sizeof(source) - 1;
        if ((size_t)(end - buffer) < sizeof(source)-1)
            numbytes = end - buffer;
        memmove(buffer, source, numbytes);
        buffer += numbytes;
    }
}

static void test(Function f, const char *fn, const char *del, size_t numbytes)
{
    Clock clk;
    char refbuf[numbytes];
    char buffer[numbytes];
    char clkbuf[32];
    fill_bytes(refbuf, sizeof(refbuf));
    strcpy(buffer, refbuf);
    clk_init(&clk);
    clk_start(&clk);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_REPEATS; i++)
    {
        memmove(buffer, refbuf, sizeof(buffer));
        if (f)
            (*f)(buffer, del);
    }
    clk_stop(&clk);
    printf("%-17s (%4zd) = %10s (%.64s)\n", fn, numbytes,
           clk_elapsed_us(&clk, clkbuf, sizeof(clkbuf)), buffer);
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int size = 2; size <= 2048; size = size * 4)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
           test(s_strip1, "s_strip1:strpbrk:", "AJQRSTajqrst234567=+[]", size);
           test(s_strip2, "s_strip2:strchr:",  "AJQRSTajqrst234567=+[]", size);
           test(s_strip3, "s_strip3:map",      "AJQRSTajqrst234567=+[]", size);
           test(0,        "s_strip4:null",     "AJQRSTajqrst234567=+[]", size);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Micro-optimizations

```
extern char *s_strip4(char *s, const char *del);
extern char *s_strip5(char *s, const char *del);

char *s_strip5(char *s, const char *del)
{
    char map[256];
    const unsigned char *up1 = (const unsigned char *)del;
    unsigned char *up2 = (unsigned char *)s;
    unsigned char *up3 = (unsigned char *)s;

    memset(map, 1, sizeof(map));

    while (*up1 != '\0')
        map[*up1++] = 0;

    for ( ; *up2 != '\0'; up2++)
    {
        *up3 = *up2;
        up3 += map[*up2];
    }
    *up3 = '\0';

    return (char *)up3;
}

char *s_strip4(char *s, const char *del)
{
    char map[256] = { 0 };
    const unsigned char *up1 = (const unsigned char *)del;
    unsigned char *up2 = (unsigned char *)s;
    unsigned char *up3 = (unsigned char *)s;

    while (*up1 != '\0')
        map[*up1++] = 1;

    for ( ; *up2 != '\0'; up2++)
    {
        *up3 = *up2;
        up3 += !map[*up2];
    }
    *up3 = '\0';

    return (char *)up3;
}
```

Comment: This is just brilliant Jonathan, brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: @Harry: it is also untested - beware!  The biggest performance hit might well be in setting the map to all zero.

Comment: possible micro-optimization:  replace inner loop with `*up3=*up2; up3+=!map[*up2];`.  The thinking is that on branching and loop mis-prediction can be expensive.  This replaces the `if` with a fixed sequence of instructions.   But definitely test on your processor family to see if this makes a difference.

Comment: @AShelly: the micro-optimization is very worthwhile on my test box.  And since what you suggested worked well, I inverted the logic of `map`, using `memset()` to initialize the map to all 1's, then avoiding the `!` in the loop, which gave another fillip to the times.

Answer (score 3):

What about using `strchr()` instead of `strpbrk()`?

Your version loops over the input string unnecessarily, when you only need to check the 1st character.

```
/* ... */
if (!strchr(del, *cp1)) *cp2++ = *cp1;
/* ... */
```

Comment: You are absolutely right pmg, thank you (that part was... itching me for a while, but I couldn't nail it down... many thx again). Now, I'm wondering about Daniel's comment, what's that overflow attack vulnerability he pointed out?

Comment: I think Daniel made a mistake in his comment. Assuming the inputs are regular strings, I don't see how you can write beyond the end of the input.

Comment: @pmg: Well, that's the assumption, isn't it?

Comment: The fact that both `s` and `del` are "honest to C" strings is reflected in the function documentation -- I say that passing anything else to `s_strip()` is Undefined Behavior and not the function responsability.

Comment: that's right, the functions does assume s and del are null-terminated strings

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `strpbrk`, it is going to scan forward through the string, looking for a character in `del`.  If you call this with a 100 character long string which contains no "deletable" characters, it is going to check 100+99+98+97+...+1 characters.

Why not make better use of the information `strpbrk` returns?   If the return value is null, you can return the original string.  Otherwise, you can use all the characters up to the pointer returned by strpbrk.

Something like:

```
 dest=src=s;
 bad = strpbrk(src,del);
 if (!bad) return s;  //early exit if there is no work.
 while (bad)
 {
    while (src<bad) *dst++=*src++;
    bad = strpbrk(++src,del);
 }
 while (*src) *dst++=*src++; //copy the remainder
 *dst='\0';
 return s;
```

Comment: Wow guys, I cannot keep up with the pace! Plz, give me some time to comprehend that one! At a fist glance it looks better even  than pmg's suggestion (which I've already put with an edit in the original code above). Is that right?

Comment: I don't know if it is better or not. The advantage of this one is it only makes 1 function call per character matching `del`. But it processes each character 2x (once inside strpbrk, once to copy.) @pmg's solution makes only a single pass, but makes a function call for each character. If speed has been shown to be a concern, profiling can tell you which is faster. If this is not a time-critical function, then the better choice is the one that is more readable to you (and your team)

Comment: I like this.  I wonder if there's mileage in using `memmove()` in place of the inner while loop?  A good modern compiler might optimize it by inlining the code to a couple of assembler instructions.  Since the copying is being done in place, you cannot use  `memcpy()`, of course.

Comment: That might be a good idea, @Jonathan.  I also realized that you don't have to copy the characters between 0 and the first `bad`.  Simply move `src = dest = bad` right before the while loop.